# Injecting properties into classes like VelocityEngineFactoryBean using Guice similar to Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice, velocity

I'm trying to inject an instance of **org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean** in my code using **Guice**. But not sure about how to specify the Property **velocityProperties** of this Bean.

Currently in Spring, I can do it using.

```
<bean id="velocityEngine"
        class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
                <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">
                    org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The Class VelocityEngineFactoryBean doesn't have this property with @Inject annotation.

```
public class VelocityEngineFactoryBean extends VelocityEngineFactory
        implements FactoryBean<VelocityEngine>, InitializingBean, ResourceLoaderAware {

    private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;
```

Neither does it provide a setter for this.

1. So how do I inject objects like these in my code using Guice?
2. In general, how do I create an object of this type and use it in code?

Comment: You tried following Guice guide and it did not work for you?

Comment: Yes, I followed it. But couldn't find anything which could perform this.
There's `bindProperties` but that needs the corresponding class to use `@Inject` to bind the properties. Since this is compiled as jar I cannot do it.
The work around I'm doing to achieve this is write a **wrapper** for actual VelocityEngine or Use **Reflection** with Guice.
But both these approaches seems to be a hacky way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I Implemented it.

1. Write a custom wrapper around apache VelocityEngine instead of using VelocityEngineFactoryBean.
2. Use providers to inject them in Guice.

This worked.

```
 @Provides
        VelocityEngine velocityEngine() throws Exception {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("resource.loader", "class");
            props.put("class.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
            return new VelocityEngine(props);
        }
```

Guice would Inject the VelocityEngine.

There was another way to do it if I wanted to use **VelocityEngineFactoryBean**, using `reflection and Provides` to create an instance of VelocityEngineFactoryBean.
However this looked more like a hack, so thought I'll directly create an instance of Apache's engine instead of using Spring.